# How do polynomial contrasts work in ANOVA?

Tags: anova, contrasts

I'm struggling to understand contrasts in the context of ANOVA generally and repeated measures ANOVA specifically. I have experimental data where each subject did a task with 4 levels of difficulty: 1 (baseline), 2, 4, and 6.

I expected my DV to decrease as difficulty level increased. I ran a RM ANOVA, but was instructed that either a polynomial contrast or a Helmert contrast is an appropriate follow-up. The polynomial weights apparently need to be specified as (1, 2, 4, 6) given that the spacing is meaningful (increasing difficulty). This gives an SPSS output of a table with linear, quadratic, and cubic effects with some information including F and p values, but it does not have any regression parameter estimates...

Coming from the ANOVA approach I am a bit confused as to what is happening here. For example, I thought I had to run multiple contrasts that each sum to 0... Could somebody explain this in simple terms please? I couldn't find much information from googling this.